# Page elements not recognized on different machine while initializing through PageFactory method

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Dear friends and colleagues

Here is a wierd scenario or may be someone already facing this issue not sure but see for yourself.

Consider there are 5 fields initialized using PageFactory method. 3 fields are on login page which is already loaded in DOM and remaining 2(Home page after login) fields are not yet loaded in DOM.

Now when I start the login test from my machine remotely on some other client using grid, it works fine.

But when I start the test from another machine remotely on same client using grid does not work.

My toolset
Language binding => C#  WebDriver 2.47.0, TestRunner => Gallio/mBUnit, Browser => Any(Chrome/FF),  DotNet Grid Standalone Server 2.47.1

I have a Login function where all page elements are initialized through PageFactory method as given below

public LoginFunction(driver)
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
        }

Elements are declared as below

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = @"#UserName")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement UserNameTextField { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = @"#Password")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement PasswordTextField { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = @".span2>input")] //input[@value='Sign in']")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement LoginButton { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = @"//h2[contains(text(),'Welcome, admin')]")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement WelcomeFormMessageText { get; set; }

   [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = @"tabslist")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement MainTabsList { get; set; }
```

Now when the PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this); statement executes, the test fails while initializing WelcomeFormMessageText IWebElement which is actually not present in DOM. These elements are present on Home page after login is successful.

Now the question is the same test runs fine when I run it from my machine and fails when I run it from another machine :-(

Both the machine configs are same having identical OS, browser versions, bit systems etc.

I have tried to run the test on third machine and it fails there too. It only seems to run from my m/c.

Has anyone seen this issue? or have any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Running tests on a remote machine is usually slower than running it locally.
I think it is due to a delay after login to get to the home page on your remote machine and hence you are not able to see the elements on Homepage because HomePage is not loaded yet.

Try adding a wait after login and then access the elements on the HomePage, it should work.

You also need to re-initialize the PageFactory after login to get the newer elements on page.

Although, I highly recommend having separate PageFactory for Login and Home pages.

Comment: No, its not about the page load. Its something else. The reason is, when I comment WelcomeFormMessageText element, it does not fail there, it fails on the next element This means, the object needs to be initialized when the page is available. But if thats the case, how come it works when I run test from my machine? That's where my real question is.

Comment: No, its not about the page load. Its something else. The reason is, when I comment WelcomeFormMessageText element, it does not fail there, it fails on the next element This means, the object needs to be initialized when the page is available. But if thats the case, how come it works when I run test from my machine? That's where my real question is. I have been running the 300 odd tests since past 1 year when the WebDriver version was 2.42 and never faced this issue.

Comment: ok let's not re-initialize the page, just try adding a wait after login and see if it passes on the remote machine, we will take it from there.

Comment: I guess, I am not putting the things rightly. I mean, when I say, test runs from my m/c means, I start the test from my m/c but the actual test runs in the browser on another client machine say (M1) via grid. And when I run the same test from another machine but on the same client M1, it fails. So you see its something else that I am wondering at. Its really not the page load times, I have tried that with 20 secs and really used WebDriverWait as well but no luck.